Movie with woman pretending to be unconscious to trap gang members
I remember seeing it on late night TV about 10 years ago, so its older than that.
I only remember one scene in the movie/TV show. A group of gangbangers discover a woman unconscious on the ground, purse, jewelry and such scattered around her. The thugs comment on their luck and start stealing all the valuables. One thug gets the idea to rape the woman and gets into the position.
Suddenly the woman snaps awake, smiles, and locks her legs around the thug's head, strangling him. Her and another man (who appears from nearby, I don't remember how) murder him and the rest of the gangbangers, taking selfies, beating them with their own limbs, getting covered in blood, all while smiling and laughing. Happy music plays.
Anyone remember this scene, and the movie/show it came from?

The over-the-top violence you are describing makes me think it's Alien Avengers, (1997).

Charlie and Rhonda are a sweet and comfortable married couple on
  vacation with their lovely daughter Daphne. They find a rundown
  boarding house and its haggard owner, Joseph, an ex-con whose mother
  has just died and left him the house. He doesn't know why this
  cheerful couple would want to vacation in the worst part of Los
  Angeles, but he doesn't know they're vacationing from outer space, and
  their idea of fun is murdering lowlife out on the streets.

This clip on Youtube doesn't show the actual dismemberment, but it does give an idea of the mood of the film.
